# iOS: CoreData relationships and temporary objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Does a relationship between NSManagedObjects get set, if the objects are still only temporary and not yet persisted? In my application, the relationship doesn't seem to be set after I use addObject on a temporary NSManagedObject with an one-to-many relationship.

**Edit: Code for adding the object to the relationship**

```
Child* child = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Child" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
[child setName:nameTextField.text];
[parent addChildObject:child];
```

Comment: Show your code for creating the objects and setting the relationship contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: yes. All changes you make to an unsaved context are recorded as expected. They will be persisted once you save.

Assuming there is a one-to-many relationship note that it is easier to write

```
child.parent = parent;
```

If you do not save the context the changes will be lost. Check if your `parent` is not `nil` and that you save in time before the context becomes invalid (e.g. if you deallocate a view controller that holds the context).

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that one, too. And the result was the same. Even after explicitly stating that child.parent = parent, the child inside the context had nil for a parent.
The parent and child are both in the same managedObjectContext, but there is simply no relation between them...

Comment: Are you sure your MOC is not nil?

Comment: As stated, you should step through the code and check for `nil` both for parent object and context. Also, do can do a save and see if it persists.

Comment: I'm an idiot. The context was nil, but the problem laid with passing the Parent object to the Child's ViewController. I had the InterfaceBuilders modal action and my own action where the Parent is passed both for the button and only the modal action was called so that the parent was never passed and the child.parent would be given a nil value...should have seen that...thanks guys